# AppCompat Spinner style background with colorBackground set in AppTheme?

Tags: android, colors, background, spinner, material-design

I have a BaseActivity with a theme applied in which i have defined an attribute colorBackground as my app's default background color(say brown).

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/app_background</item>
        </style>
```

What this does, is it gives the spinner present in one of the fragment loaded on that activity the same color background as my app's background(brown).
like this:
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3B9L.jpg)

But I want the style to be default with white background only and not the colorBackground.

To accomplish this i have created a style for Spinner
as

```
 <style name="AppSpinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
```

and i am applying this style as

```
     <Spinner
                            style="@style/AppSpinner
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            />
```

this gives me the the white background for the Drop down popup but surrounded by a weird black background.
like this:
[tried solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtgGY.jpg)

I tried other attributes also in the AppSpinner like
android:background and android:colorBackground also, but same result.

Why is that? How can i change that.
Or is there any other way of accomplishing the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and solved it like this:

#### 1. Make two version of you app theme

The second one has to inherit the first and set the `colorBackground` attribute (which isn't set in the first version). Something like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- some theme attributes, for example accent color, etc. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.WithBackground">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/app_background</item>
</style>
```

#### 2. Use the version with background as activity theme

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WithBackground" ... >
```

#### 3. Use the version without background as theme in spinner view

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

This worked perfectly for me, even without overdraw warnings.